# Why MSYS can't recognize tar-ustar option in AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE?

Tags: makefile, tar, msys

When I'm trying to run autogen from MSys 1.11 on a source, it always giving an error called,

configure.ac:9: option 'tar-ustar' not recognized

Can anyone please help me to get-rid of this error ?

Note:
andtar-v7, tar-ustar, tar-pax. all these 3 didn't work. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the tar-ustar option from your configure.ac file (look for an AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE line) or install a newer version of Automake (1.9+).  It should fall back to v7-style tar (in spite of not recognizing tar-v7).

Answer (score -1):

tar is the command - the '-' and the letters after it is a parameter. You want:

```
 tar -ustar
```

notice the space. Having said that, I don't believe that `-ustar` is a valid combination of tar options, but you should get a different error message for that.

Comment: Hey! are you talking about AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE() also ? Because, in ubuntu it works nicely. The problem occurs when I'm trying it with MSys1.1.